# How can I make "man" or "nano" available on Git Bash on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, git, bash

so today on class they taught me a little about what we can do on a terminal using a Mac. We were going to work with Git so we had to download the components from git-gsm.com, but my personal computer runs in Windows and since windows does not have a terminal, Git brought a Bash with it so that it can be used as the one in Mac and Linux.

The thing is in class we used commands like man and nano, and my windows bash does not recognize them

how can I make it so?

Comment: For Windows Git uses [CYGWIN](https://www.cygwin.com/), in order to ahieve the same Linux look&feel. Git will work the same way on Windows as well. ["Windows Subsystem for Linux"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/commandline/wsl/about) might be interesting fot you as well.

Comment: to be honest with you this confuses me a little more. I am really new at this therefore I do not really know which path should I go for.

Comment: Git will work the same way. CYGWIN has nano and man as well. You can use whatever IDE/editor you feel comfortable with. Nano is used, I think, because it should be available on a fresh instalation of Linux.

Comment: Another recommendation for cygwin. Trying to set up a "minimal" dev environment is fruitless, make a full one. Use its package manager to install whatever programs/libs you want.

Comment: But seriously, set aside some time to learn a real editor like `vim` sooner or later.

Comment: Download gnu nano WinNT/9x binary: https://coderwall.com/p/ee-law/use-nano-from-git-bash-on-windows-d

Answer (score 0):

Git on windows comes bundled with a full build of bash along with a substantial subset of the linux command commandline tools.

Running under the name git-bash it's literally just the raw source compiled to run on windows. It will run pretty much exactly the same as it's windows siblings. Anything you did in your class you can also do in git bash.

The main reason for this is a large chunk of linux runs using these basic command line tools. Even if you use git from the windows command prompt, git for windows will still call out to this bash to perform all its internal actions.

It's actually so good and contains a large enough subset of tools that I've uninstalled the CYGWIN build of bash from most of my machines and just use the version of bash bundled with git.

If you installed git through the windows installer with the standard configuration, git bash will be in your start menu and be accessible by right clicking in any folder and selecting 'Git Bash Here'